# How to get checkbox value when checked in MVC using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to get the value of checkbox when it is checked. I am getting `varchar` value from database for this checkbox.

If `A1` is checked then `varchar` value should be `1` and if `A2` checked then `varchar` value should be `2`.

Please suggest me how to get these values?

Model

```
    public string IsA1 { get; set; }
    public string IsA2 { get; set; }
    public string IsA3 { get; set; }


    public bool A1Value
    {
        get { return IsA1 == "1"; }
        set { IsA1 = value ? "1" : "0"; }
    }

    public bool A2Value
    {
        get { return IsA2 == "1"; }
        set { IsA2 = value ? "1" : "0"; }
    }
    public bool A3Value
    {
        get { return IsA3 == "1"; }
        set { A3 = value ? "1" : "0"; }
    }
```

View

```
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsA1, "A1")
     @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.A1Value,new { @class = "chk"})
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsA2, "A2")
     @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.A2Value, new { @class = "chk"})
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsA3, "A3")
     @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.A3Value, new { @class = "chk"})
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult ABC()
  {
      Details details = new Details();

            var model = new ClsS();

            model.IsA1 = "1";
            model.IsA2 = "2";
            model.IsA3 = "3";

            model.spartial = details.spartialSQL(model.IsA1, model.IsA2, model.IsA3);             

            return View(model);
   }
```

Script

```
 $('.chk').prop('checked', true);
      $('.chk').on('change',function () {
          if ($(this).is(':checked')) {               
             /////
          }

      });
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You are editing data so always use a view model which will contain just `bool` properties (and you map from the data model to the view and vice versa

Comment: @User9895 Not quite sure what you're asking, here. `$(this).val()`, where you have `/////`, is how you read the value of the checkbox, regardless of how the input was generated.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, What I want is that if A1 is checked then value should be 1 and so on. Please suggest me.

Comment: And what happens when all are checked? It looks like what you really want are radio buttons.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, if all are checked then, I have to pass the value 1,2,3 respectively.

Comment: Are you storing coma separated values in your database? (what is this `varchar` property that you are binding to)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Currently when page loads, I am passing all the value which you can see in my controller. Once page is loaded then I want the value based on check and uncheck.

Comment: Yes Stephen. For instance, for A1 , the value is `1`, for `A2` the value `2` and so on.

Comment: @TiesonT., I do not want `true` or `false`. I want the value for each checkbox.

Comment: I would suggest that your model is sub-optimal. You probably want something like a MultiSelectList, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dd470159(v=vs.118), which you can use to build up what is more or less a checkbox list.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Please guide me.

Comment: Your view model will have 3 properties - `public bool IsA1 { get; set; }` etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Please provide me a solution if possible then. Thank you.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Can you please help me?

Comment: @User9895, I have already stated that your view model should just include 3 `bool` properties which you bind the checkboxes to. I am not sure what else you are expecting. But like all your questions where you just make up this code that has no relationship to your actual project, its almost impossible to understand what you are really trying to do. (your project does not contain properties `IsA1` etc, and I cannot understand why you keep making up this code)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, If I include `bool` then how can i send `varchar` value. This `bool` always gives me either true or false. As I mentioned before, If `A` is ticked then value 1 should pass and if `B` is checked then value 2 and so on.

Comment: You map your view model to the data model - `if(viewModel.IsA1) { yourDataModelProperty = 1; }` etc (I do not even know what your `varchar` property is because of your continued instance in writing this ridiculous code in your questions, and more importantly why in the world you have a `varchar` property in the first place when you clearly should have `bool` fields or an `[Flags]enum`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172053/discussion-between-user9895-and-stephen-muecke).